# Using output of FOR EACH SMO Enumerator as Data Control Source

Tags: ssis

This is a follow-on to my previous question about FOR EACH SMO Enumerator. I now have a working FOR EACH SMO Enumberator. I set it up to loop through the tables in my data base and put the name of the table in a variable User::TableName.

Now comes the problem. I want to use each table name as the Source in a Data Flow Control Task that simply uses the table Name as the Source and an Excel Spreadsheet as the Destination. In setting up the Source for the Data Flow Task I can't find a place to say that the Source is a Variable and that it can be found in User::TableName.

Can you tell me how to do this. I tried going into the properties of the Destination Connection Manager and setting the Connection String to User::TableName, but this doesn't seem to work.

Thanks,

Dick

Comment: Which Data Source component you use? Is it OLE DB Source?

Comment: If you are using `OLEDB Source` just select the source type as `Table name from Variable`